# If $f'(x)\rightarrow \infty$ then $f(x)\rightarrow\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to show: $f'(x)\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ then $f(x)\rightarrow \infty$, as $x\rightarrow \infty$ and $x>0$? Here $f'$ is derivative of $f$.

Intuitively it is clear but got stuck when trying to prove it.

Comment: Not true.   Example, $f(x)=x$. There are much "wilder" examples. Just knowing that $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$ tells us little about $f'(x)$.

Comment: There was a mistake from myside. Extremely sorry. I edited it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the amended question, if $f'(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, then there is a $B$ such that $f'(x)\gt 1$ for all $x\gt B$. But then if $x\gt B$, by the Mean Value Theorem we have 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(B)}{x-B}=f'(c)\gt 1$$
for some $c$ between $B$ and $x$.

It follows that if $x\gt B$ then $f(x)\gt f(B)+(x-B)$. The right-hand side goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Got the point. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome. It can be somewhat tricky to go from "local" information (the derivative) to "global" information. The MVT does the job, as would integration.

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. The easiest counterexample is simply $f(x)=x$, whose derivative is the constant function $f'(x)=1$.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in my question. I edited it. Please see my correct question.

Answer (score 1):

f(x)=cx for any positive real constant c can be a counterexample as when x tends to infinity, f(x) tends to infinity but f'(x)=c for all x.

Answer (score 0):

Hint but degree of equation should be at least $2$ then $f(x)=ax^2+bx+x$ then $f'(x)=2ax+b$ otherwise counter examples are given